# Noun for the act of walking through a gate

Tags: nouns

### Noun

I am looking for the noun that generally describes the act of walking through a gate.

There are clear nouns for this act when there is an attached direction, i.e.:

- **entrance**, which describes entering through a gate.
- **exit**, which describes leaving through a gate.

Is there a noun that covers both of these?

#### German

In German, there is a noun for this exact act: [**Durchgang**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Durchgang).

The best translation for this word would be **passage**, which does also fit the requirements as it cannot only be used for a passage but also for the act of passing through that passage. However, I have the feeling that you would be off calling walking through a *small* gate "passage".

#### Transit

Another word that fits the requirements according to definition is **transit**, but I again have the feeling that a transit is usually something *bigger* than just walking through a small gate.

---

Is there another word that describes the act of walking through a gate? Am I wrong to assume that *passage* or *transit* do not fit perfectly?

Comment: The verb phrase for this would be "cross the threshold", which could be nouned to "threshold-crossing"

Comment: Also to your *passage* idea, the smaller *pass* might carry smaller meaning. Often we use *pass* for the permission to cross a gate, but it can also referent to the movement itself: "an act or instance of moving past or through something" (NOAD)

Comment: In English, we often use gerunds in cases like this.  going through the gate,

Comment: "[Durchgang](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/durchgang)" doesn't mean specifically passing through a gate: it has many associated meanings around passages, passageways, corridors, etc. The question seems based on a misconception.

Comment: Closest in English to _Durchgang_ is a _pass-through_, which is uncommon but cognate,  and would be understood by anyone in an architectural context.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, it does have many meanings - the same way passage does. What I was trying to express is that "Durchgang" perfectly fits entrance + exit while passage and transit do not (how I feel about it).

Comment: @Lambie I am looking for a single noun - I am trying to name something, hence the question.

Comment: I can't believe English would have a dedicated single-word noun specifically for going through *gates*. But if the gate was in fact a ***turnstile*** gate between two fields both containing angry bulls, you could expect to be understood with, say, *The rambler risked being gored in either field, but he knew he was perfectly safe during the **turnstile gate traversal** itself*.

Comment: We don't have words that are specific to walking through openings: gates, doorways, arches, etc. In English, you pass, go, walk, etc, through an opening. There just is no single word. passage is too heavy for such an ephemeral act.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like to use this word?

Comment: In French this would be the verb *franchir*, which you would usually translate as the single word *crossing*, or the two words *passing through*

Comment: Further to FumbleFingers's Comment, I can't believe that if English had a dedicated single-word noun specifically for going through gates, it would work for either or both directions.

To me it seems you are at least not correct to assume that "passage" or "transit" do not fit perfectly. What makes you say that?